# local work but hosting on AppHarbor can not query SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

So I have my `web.config` connection string pointing to my SQL Server on appharbor - from local (running Visual Studios) I can login and the memberships works. However from the build that is on the hosting side I get sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

This is strange because I made a new user from local and check with SQL Server Management Studio whether or not the data has been added to the hosting server and it WORKS.

From my latest build I get the error:

> Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.

which is weird because they both point to the same server...

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC project has the `"HandleErrorAttribute"` on by default. You should remove it from `FilterConfig.cs` in `App_Start` Folder to see the actual error rather than the handled response.

It's located in the RegisterGlobalFilters method where `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

AppHarbor has a [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions) to help you troubleshoot deployment errors like these. In particular, you should inspect the "Errors" interface on AppHarbor and disable customErrors. Please elaborate the question if the FAQ doesn't help you solve the problem.